# YouTube Upload using API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

What Does this mean?

I get this error after uploading one video.
I thought this would make my youtube uploading mess easier.
Can anyone help me with it?

```
client_secret.json-youtube-v3-(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'],)
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']
youtube service created successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/dipes/OneDrive/Desktop/Upload YouTube/upload.py", line 197, in <module>
    response_upload = service.videos().insert(
  File "C:\Users\dipes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dipes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 907, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatus&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota">quota</a>.">
```

Answer (score 3):

From the error message:

```
"The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your <link> quota"
```

You have exceded your quota read more about here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

In short:

From the link above:
Google calculates your quota usage by assigning a cost to each request. Different types of operations have different quota costs. For example:

- A read operation that retrieves a list of resources -- channels, videos, playlists -- usually costs 1 unit.
- A write operation that creates, updates, or deletes a resource usually has costs 50 units.
- A search request costs 100 units.
- A video upload costs 1600 units.